# Swift 3 how to store a struct in a "Data" object

Tags: struct

What is the "right" way to stuff an arbitrary, odd sized struct into a swift 3 Data object ?
I think that I have got there, but it seems horribly convoluted for what from prior experience was no than

```
  dataObject.append(&structInstance, sizeof(structInstance))
```

My case is as follows:

The structure of interest:

```
public struct  CutEntry {
  var itemA  : UInt64
  var itemB  : UInt32
}
```

I have an array of these things that I want to stuff into a data object, in a specific manner as the data object becomes a file which is eventually read by a different application on a different architecture.

The function to put them into a Data object

```
  open func encodeCutsData() -> Data
  {
    var data = Data()
    for entry in cutsArray
    {
      // bigendian stuff, as a var, just so the you can get the address
      var entryCopy = CutEntry(itemA: entry.itemA.bigEndian, itemB: entry.itemB.bigEndian)
      // step 1 get the address of the item as a UnsafePointer
      let d2 = withUnsafePointer(to: &entryCopy) { return $0}
      // step 2 cast it to a raw pointer
      let d3 = UnsafeRawPointer(d2)
      // step 3 create a temp data object
      let d4 = Data(bytes:d3, count: MemoryLayout<CutEntry>.size )
      // step 4 add the temp to main data object
      data.append(d4)
    }
    return data
  }
```

Earlier when we only had NSMutableData it was

```
    let item = NSMutableData()

    for entry in cutsArray
    {
      var entryCopy = CutEntry(cutPts: entry.cutPts.bigEndian, cutType: entry.cutType.bigEndian)
      item.append(&entryCopy, length: MemoryLayout<CutEntry>.size)
   }
```

I've spent a few hours searching for examples of manipulating struct and Data objects.  I though that I was close when I found references to unsafebufferpointer.  That blew up in my face when I discovered that "buffer"  bit uses core memory alignment (which can be useful) and it was stuffing 16 bytes into the data object instead of the expected 12.

I am quite prepared to say that I have missed the blindingly obvious bit of RTFM somewhere.  Can anyone offer a cleaner solution ? or has Swift really gone backwards here ?

If I could find a way of getting a pointer to the item as a UInt8 pointer that would remove a couple of lines, but that looks just a difficult.

Answer (score 0):

With checking the [reference of `Data`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data), I can find two things which may be useful for you:

[init(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer, count: Int)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780158-init)

[func append(Data)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779795-append)

You can write something like this:

```
var data = Data()
for entry in cutsArray {
    var entryCopy = CutEntry(cutPts: entry.cutPts.bigEndian, cutType: entry.cutType.bigEndian)
    data.append(Data(bytes: &entryCopy, count: MemoryLayout<CutEntry>.size))
}
```

Comment: Ah bugger, wrap in a Data initialiser, that simple.  Many thanks,  I kept saying to  myself, "it just can't be this hard..."